# Getting doubling twice for box's width

Tags: python

I try to get the final answer as (32, 56) but then it throws me the result as (32, 112). I'm sure this happens because my double function issue after it has been calling twice, one for getting length and another for getting width. Below is my example codes.

```py
class Box:
    ## Constructor declaration.
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.__length = length
        self.__width = width

    ## A method that doubles the size of a box.
    def double(self):

        self.__length = self.get_length() * 2
        self.__width = self.get_width() * 2
        return self

    ## A method that gets length of a box.
    def get_length(self):
        return self.__length

    ## A method that gets width of a box.
    def get_width(self):
        return self.__width

    def combine(self, other):
       self.__length = self.__length + other.get_length()
       self.__width = self.__width + other.get_width()
       return self


box1 = Box(5,10)
box2 = Box(3,4)
box3 = Box(5,10)

box1.combine(box3)
box2.double()
box1.combine(box2)

print(box1.double().get_length())
print(box1.double().get_width())
```

Comment: So, why do you call it twice?

Comment: I'm running a unit test as this self.assertEqual(b1.double().get_length(),32), self.assertEqual(b1.double().get_width(),56)

Comment: Well, I guess you should run some other test. Or accept the fact that the box is doubled twice.

Answer (score 0):

Literally what you said in your question - you're doubling it twice.

```py
box1.double()
print(box1.get_length())  # 32
print(box1.get_width())   # 56
```

Comment: The print statement just to check the double values. I have a unit test as below and it does not pass for the second one. self.assertEqual(b1.double().get_length(),32), self.assertEqual(b1.double().get_width(),56)

Comment: Similarly, your first test doubles both length and width of `b1`, and so length is 32 and width is 56. When you make the second call, they double again, and so now your comparison fails as the width is 112. If you just do the `double()` once and then check both values, it will pass.

Comment: Then you have to assert that the value will be 112.

Comment: but 112 is not the answer. The correct answer is 56. That is why I try to figure out why the code i wrote is throwing me 112 but not 56.